# UI Testing in Swift Package

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift-package-manager

I am building a Swift Package library that provide some UI components, for both macOS and iOS.

I would like to be able to test this codebase and cover my code with unit test for both platforms.

Is there a way to manage that ?

Answer (score 2):

As of Swift 5.4, the Swift Package Manager doesn't provide that functionality out of the box.

To carry out UI tests, you need to create a separate app (in its separate xcode project), whose only purpose is to import the package and run UI tests via `xcodebuild` commands (as `swift test` won't work).

Comment: But if I do that, I can't get JUST the swift package code coverage, due to [this](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/133517) terrible bug.